# Floating point rounding error when computing the power of a double-float number

Tags: floating-point, lisp, common-lisp

I want to develop a Common Lisp solution to [Leetcode problem 50. "Pow(x, n)"](https://leetcode.com/problems/powx-n/) which asks:

> "Implement pow(x, n), which calculates x raised to the power n (i.e.,
> x^n)."

My direct solution is :

```
(defun pow (x n)
  (declare (ftype (function (double-float fixnum) double-float) pow))
  (if (zerop n)
      1d0
      (let ((r 1d0))
        (dotimes (i (abs n)) (setf r (* r x)))
        (if (plusp n)
            r
            (/ 1d0 r)))))

(pow 2.1d0 3)
=> 9.261000000000001d0
```

Why does it have a 1 at the 15th digit after period ? How can I get the result without this rounding error ?

My Common Lisp implementation : SBCL 2.3.4 on linux.

Comment: Floats are binary and 1/10 goes on forever, but floats have a limited size so you get rounding errors. It's the same with 1/3 for decimal. See [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: Your declaration isn't doing anything where it is placed, since `pow` doesn't call itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating with floats is not exact. Even representing numbers as floats is not exact. 1/3 is 0.3333..., where a float on a computer has limited precision.

In Common Lisp one can compute with integers and rational numbers.

Your code, but more general:

```
(defun pow (x n)
  (if (zerop n)
      1
      (let ((r 1))
        (dotimes (i (abs n)) (setf r (* r x)))
        (if (plusp n)
            r
            (/ 1 r)))))
```

Now your `2.1` might mean `21/10`, which is a number in Common Lisp.

```
CL-USER 7 > (pow 21/10 3)
9261/1000
```

We can then convert the result to a double float:

```
CL-USER 8 > (float * 1.0d0)
9.261D0
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It gave me an idea: use RATIONALIZE on x at the top the function.

Answer (score 1):

Following [Rainer Joswig answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77044298/3673), I would like to propose this solution to circumvent floating point rounding errors, using [RATIONALIZE](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_ration.htm) and [FLOAT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_float.htm) :

```
(defun pow (x n)
  (setf x (rationalize x))
  (float
   (if (zerop n)
       1
       (let ((r 1))
         (dotimes (i (abs n)) (setf r (* r x)))
         (if (plusp n)
             r
             (/ 1 r))))
   1.0d0))

(pow 2.0d0 10)
=> 1024.0d0

(pow 2.1d0 3)
=> 9.261d0

(pow 2.0d0 -2)
=> 0.25d0
```